# modrewrite php query string

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I would like to change:

> http://example.com/index.php?p=blog&pid=2&lid=1&l=en

into just

> http:// example.com/en/blog.html

or just

> http:// example.com/blog.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* that you are trying to achieve more friendly URLs, so I'm assuming that wan to internally rewrite `http://example.com/en/blog.html` to `http://example.com/index.php?p=blog&pid=2&lid=1&l=en`.

The most practical way that I can recommend is to rewrite everything to your PHP script, and do the rewriting internally in PHP. That way your PHP application can have full control over URIs.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

In PHP, you can then access the original URI via superglobals: `$_SERVER[ "REQUEST_URI" ]`. Note: sanitize, sanitize, sanitize!

---

***Edit***

If you want to do the whole thing via `.htaccess`, then see the example below. Note however that if you'll expand your URI structure in the future (i.e. by adding new rules), then this approach might become more difficult to maintain as opposed to doing it within your PHP application.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# http://example.com/en/blog.html
RewriteRule ^([^\/]*)/([^\/]*)\.html$ index.php?l=$1&p=$2 [NC,QSA,L]

# http://example.com/blog.html
RewriteRule ^([^\/]*)\.html$ index.php?p=$1 [NC,QSA,L]

# alternatively you can change the last line to add a default language (if not present)
RewriteRule ^([^\/]*)\.html$ index.php?l=sk&p=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

***Edit #2:*** added a missing `^` character in all three rules, i.e. changed `([\/]*)` to `([^\/]*)`

Comment: http://example.com/en/blog.html to http://example.com/index.php?p=blog&pid=2&lid=1&l=en.
-- i think it's the other way around. but I do get your idea.

Comment: I see. Are you trying to rewrite or redirect the URLs? I'd understand the latter as a way of not breaking legacy links to your existing site, while trying to upgrade the URI design. If that's the case, then you can safely use the above, as the original links (.../index.php?p=blog&...) will still work.

Comment: I think you are right, I have rewrite my URLs using PHP to make it flexible. thanks a lot!